# Resistance measurement using loop resistance technique

Tags: arduino-nano

Im trying do a circuit to measure resistance between Neutral and ground, for this I tried ohm law method i.e., to obtain R = (V/I). Voltage is known value 25 Vac, Current value is measured using ACS712 and tried the coding is given below, I'm getting current value from it, but when I apply ohms law I'm not getting resistance value.Please guide me

```
/*
Measuring AC Current Using ACS712
*/
const int sensorIn = A0;
int mVperAmp = 185; // use 100 for 20A Module and 66 for 30A Module


double Voltage = 0;
double VRMS = 0;
double AmpsRMS = 0;



void setup(){ 
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){


 Voltage = getVPP();
 VRMS = (Voltage/2.0) *0.707; 
 AmpsRMS = (VRMS * 1000)/mVperAmp;
 Serial.print(AmpsRMS);
 Serial.println(" Amps RMS");

}

float getVPP()
{
  float result;

  int readValue;             //value read from the sensor
  int maxValue = 0;          // store max value here
  int minValue = 1024;          // store min value here

   uint32_t start_time = millis();
   while((millis()-start_time) < 1000) //sample for 1 Sec
   {
       readValue = analogRead(sensorIn);
       // see if you have a new maxValue
       if (readValue > maxValue) 
       {
           /*record the maximum sensor value*/
           maxValue = readValue;
       }
       if (readValue < minValue) 
       {
           /*record the maximum sensor value*/
           minValue = readValue;
       }
   }

   // Subtract min from max
   result = ((maxValue - minValue) * 5.0)/1024.0;

   return result;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome on this board! To increase the chance of getting a proper answer you should describe what you did, waht you expect and what didn't work as expected. Also please format your code (just select your code and press the`{}`-button).

Comment: What values do you actually get?

Comment: you should rename the variables